# Where clause if null show all, if where = $variable show $variable

Tags: php, select, mysqli, where-clause

I'm a bit stuck on a bit of code im doing.

Here's the code i already have

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" >
<select name="sortby" class="sortby" >
        <option value=" ORDER BY id DESC">Date Added (Newest First)</option>
        <option value=" ORDER BY id ASC">Date Added (Oldest First)</option>
        <option value="ORDER BY clicks DESC">Website Clicks </option>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
      </select>
</form>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<select name="country" class="sortby">
<option value="">Country...</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
.... and so on
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

PHP code:

```
$sortby = $_POST['sortby'];
$sortby = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sortby);
$country = $_POST ['country'];
$country = $mysqli->real_escape_string($country);


$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, link, image, title, description, country, clicks FROM isc_links WHERE approved=1 $sortby");


while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

    print '<div id="linkmainwrapper"><div id="linkwrapper"><div class="linkimageborder"><div class="linkimage"><a href="http://'.$row["link"].'" target="_blank">'.$row["image"].'</a></div></div>';
    print '<div class="linktitle"><a href="clickcounter.php?id='.$row["id"].'" target="_blank">'.$row["title"].'</a></div>';
    print '<div class="link">('.$row["link"].')</div>';
    print '<div class="countryflag"><img src="http://www.hatblocksdirect.co.uk/lib/flags/'.$row["country"].'.gif"></div>';

    print '<div class="linkdescription">'.$row["description"].'</div>';
    print '<div class="clickcount">Website Clicks ('.$row["clicks"].')</div></div></div>';
```

what i would like to do is sort colums. the first sort box works, i can sort by website clicks, id etc using $sortby.

Ive passed the `$country` using a select drop down but i dont know how to implement this into my select query. I need it to display all entries if a country hasn't been selected. once a country is selected only display that country.

Any help very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Put the additional condition of the `WHERE` clause in a variable depending on whether the parameter is supplied.

```
if (!empty($_POST['country'])) {
    $country = "AND country = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($country) . "'";
} else {
    $country = "";
}

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, link, image, title, description, country, clicks FROM isc_links WHERE approved=1 $country $sortby");
```

Comment: thanks this worked great. just what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` condition like

```
if(isset($_POST ['country']))
{    // if country is set
   $country = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST ['country']);
   $sql="SELECT id, link, image, title, description, country, clicks FROM isc_links WHERE approved=1 and country='$country' $sortby";
}
else
{  // if country is not se
   $sql="SELECT id, link, image, title, description, country, clicks FROM isc_links WHERE approved=1 $sortby";
}
$results = $mysqli->query($sql);    // execute the query
```